# How to pick a random choice using a custom probability distribution

Tags: python, performance, probability

I have a list of US names and their respective names from the US census website. I would like to generate a random name from this list using the given probability. The data is here: [US Census data](http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/data/1990surnames/dist.all.last)

I have seen algorithms like the [roulette wheel selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection) algorithm that are easy to implement, but I wanted to know if there was any way to generate random names in O(1). For [histogram data](http://www.panix.com/~murphy/bdata.txt) this is easier, as you could create a hash of integers to birthdays, but I would like to do this for a continuous distribution.

If this is not possible, are there any python modules that take in probability distributions and generate random values based on those distributions?

Comment: What sort of probability distributions are you thinking of using? Many entries in your dataset are 0.000. I think it would be better if you can find a source with more than 3 decimal places.

Comment: Couldn't you just assign each of the names proportional width, and then map a random number from 0 to 1 onto the new range?

Comment: @WaleedKhan, but the lookup in the range is O(log n)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an `O(1)`-time method  See [this detailed description of Vose's "alias" method](http://www.keithschwarz.com/darts-dice-coins/).  Unfortunately, it suffers from high initialization cost.  For comparative timings of simpler methods, see [Eli Bendersky's blog post](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/01/22/weighted-random-generation-in-python/).  More timings can be found [in this from the Python issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue18844).

Comment: Alias method is very interesting reading. I think the table generation might make a good codegolf

Comment: I think the alias method is closest to what I am looking for. The issue tracker is an interesting link too. I will have to find a better source of data to continue though.

Comment: @JDong, note that the issue tracker item has files attached containing Python implementations of all the methods Serhiy Storchaka reporting timings for.  Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 4):

These days it's practical to enumerate the entire US population (~317 million) if you really need `O(1)` lookup. Just pick a number up to 317 million and get the name from there. (317000000*4 bytes = 1.268GB)

I think there are lots of `O(log n)` ways. Is there a particular reason you need `O(1)` (They will use a lot less memory)

Comment: It was mostly theoretical, but I also wanted to know if there was a better solution than my knee jerk O(log) reaction.